# React-Native display image without declaring dimensions

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-flexbox

In, React-Native, is it possible to display an image without declaring `width` and `height` inside `style` prop ?
I would like the image to take all the space it has or to be rendered at its actual dimensions. (whether resizeMode is set to cover for example.)

I read this article and tried to implement its method but with no success : https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-react-native-images-or-saying-goodbye-to-trial-and-error-b2baaf0a1a4d

Here is my code :

```
    <View>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c8/Marvelwolverine.jpg' }}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          height: undefined,
          width: undefined,
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

but nothing gets printed unless I specify hard coded `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Image source={{ uri:'http://...'}}
                style={{
                    alignSelf: 'stretch',
                    flex: 1,
                }}
            />
        </View>
```

Comment: `resizeMode` was incorrect, but `alignSelf` works as expected. Check: https://snack.expo.io/ryhO6dSf-

Comment: I am not sure.. I got some results with resizeMode. Either setting it to ''center" or "cover", etc... Here is some changes I tried : https://snack.expo.io/BJFA-FBzZ. It seems the Image is rendered at its actual size, but it is centered...
Thanks for showing https://snack.expo.io ! Very useful.
I think the answer is good. But I believe there is more depth to this image rendering thing...